# Why this CSS is not occupying the whole page?

Tags: css, layout

I created this a CSS page demo http://jsfiddle.net/a3210pea/ using another page
http://jsfiddle.net/XGhP8/71/

The second page is occupying the whole page but the one I created is not occupying the whole page.

My CSS is this

```
 html, body {
     min-height:100%;
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
}
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
}
.middle {
    height:100%;
}
.bottom {
    background-color:blue;
}
.top {
    background-color: white;
}
.left {
    width:100px;
    background:red;
    height:100%;
}
.right {
    background:orange;
    height:100%;
}

.top.row {
   height : 6%;
   width : 100%;
   background-color : pink;
}
.row > .cell{
  width : 100%;
}
.cell > #logo {
  width : 15%;
  float : left;
}
.cell > #heading {
   width : 84%;
   text-align : center;
}
.banner {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: large;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#content_border {
   margin : 0.3em;
   border-style : solid;
   border-width : 2px;
   border-color : black;
}
img {
  max-width : 100%;
  height : auto;
}
.text {
   font-size: 2.5vw;
}
```

The CSS I am using as base is this :-

```
    html, body {
    min-height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
}
.middle {
    background-color:green;
    height:100%;
}
.bottom {
    background-color:blue;
}
.top {
    background-color:pink;
}
.left {
    width:100px;
    background:red;
    height:100%;
}
.right {
    background:orange;
    height:100%;
}
```

What mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the height of `#content_border`?

```
#content_border{
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I admit I didn't try but how it came to you that I should be trying that only? I mean this worked but how to make out that this is the missing part in my adaptation.

Comment: It's not the only solution. I just noticed that the height of your `wrapper` ID was actually set to 100%, but since you added another `div` element with an ID `content_border`, that element does not pick up the height of your `body`.

Comment: What are the possible other solution that can be applied here? Kindly elaborate

Comment: Aside from my solution, you can also fully remove the `div` you added with `id="content_border"`, then change the `#content_border` part of your css to `#wrapper`, or copy the CSS you set for `#content_border` to your `#wrapper` CSS block. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/a3210pea/4/

Answer (score 1):

As per your question you have created demo1 with referring to demo2 link, Hence in demo1 you have created new div with id `"content_border"` before table.

```
#content_border{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Why adding height to the content border is so important?

Answer (score 1):

You have to give `height:100%` to each and every parent container else parent will take default value of height which is `Auto` and its children will follow.

```
#content_border {height:100%;}
```

Comment: Why adding height to content border is so important? I mean this worked but how to make out that this is the missing part in my adaptation.

Comment: So in this case I was not using height:100% and the content was not that much hence the content_border was applying height:auto and getting shrunk

Comment: absolutely.. u got it